# Filter list using Boolean index arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x

How can I use boolean inddex arrays to filter a list without using numpy?

For example:

```
>>> l = ['a','b','c']
>>> b = [True,False,False]
>>> l[b]
```

The result should be:

```
['a']
```

I know numpy support it but want to know how to solve in Python.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = np.array(['a','b','c'])
>>> b = np.array([True,False,False])
>>> l[b]
array(['a'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python does not support boolean indexing but the [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) function does exactly what you want. It return an iterator with means you need to use the `list` constructor to return a list.

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> b = [True, False, False]
>>> list(compress(l, b))
['a']
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[a for a, t in zip(l, b) if t]
# => ["a"]
```

A bit more efficient, use iterator version:

```
from itertools import izip
[a for a, t in izip(l, b) if t]
# => ["a"]
```

EDIT: user3100115's version is nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `enumerate`

```
l = ['a','b','c']
b = [True,False,False]

res = [item for i, item in enumerate(l) if b[i]]

print(res)
```

gives

```
['a']
```