# Remove elements from python list based on filter

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have 3 lists in Python.

```
list_a = [10., 20., 30., 12.]
list_b = [30., 20., 60., 12.]
list_c = [10., 80., 90., 12.]
```

I want to drop those elements in `list_b` and `list_c` where values in `list_a` are `<= 15`. Therefore results become:

```
list_b = [20., 60.]
list_c = [80., 90.]
```

Is there a way to do this without for loops? (list comprehensions are ok)

Comment: Without loops? I don't think so. also shouldn't `list_b` be `[30.,20.,60.,]` ?

Comment: You're not using Numpy, are you? One can do this easily with Numpy arrays.

Comment: @DavidZ I am using numpy, is there a compact way to do this there?

Comment: @snakecharmerb returning new lists is ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may write a one-liner to filter the list via using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) as:

```
list_b, list_c = zip(*[(b, c) for a, b, c in zip(list_a, list_b, list_c) if a>15])
```

The final values hold by `list_b` and `list_c` will be:

```
>>> list_b
(20.0, 60.0)
>>> list_c
(80.0, 90.0)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using numpy as you said you are, in comments, you can simply create a boolean index from `a` and mask elements in `b` and `c`:

```
import numpy as np

list_a = np.array([10., 20., 30., 12.])
list_b = np.array([30., 20., 60., 12.])
list_c = np.array([10., 80., 90., 12.])

list_b = list_b[list_a>15]
list_c = list_c[list_a>15]

print list_a
print list_b
print list_c
```

Output:

```
[ 10.  20.  30.  12.]
[ 20.  60.]
[ 80.  90.]
```

You can convert the `lists_b` and `list_c` to Python `list type` by `.tolist()` method.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the little known [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) class to do this. See [Filter list using Boolean index arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837803/filter-list-using-boolean-index-arrays)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list_a = [10., 20., 30., 12.]
>>> list_b = [30., 20., 60., 12.]
>>> list_c = [10., 80., 90., 12.]
>>> bool_list = [item > 15 for item in list_a]
>>> bool_list
[False, True, True, False]
>>> list_b = list(itertools.compress(list_b, bool_list))
>>> list_b
[20.0, 60.0]
>>> list_c = list(itertools.compress(list_c, bool_list))
>>> list_c
[80.0, 90.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you use list comprehensions?

You could do it like this:

```
list_a = [10., 20., 30., 12.]
list_b = [30., 20., 60., 12.]
list_c = [10., 80., 90., 12.]
list_b = [ el for (i, el) in enumerate(list_b) if (list_a[i] > 15) ]
list_c = [ el for (i, el) in enumerate(list_c) if (list_a[i] > 15) ]
```

Snipper was written here, I haven't tested it, but you see the general idea.

I assumed that all lists are the same length. If `list_a` is shorter and you want to drop elements that are on the missing positions, you can do it like this:

```
list_b = [ el for (i, el) in enumerate(list_b) if (i<len(list_a) and list_a[i] > 15) ]
```

and if you want to keep them, just reverse the sign and boolean operator:

```
list_b = [ el for (i, el) in enumerate(list_b) if (i>=len(list_a) or list_a[i] > 15) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) like below:

```
>>> list_a = [10., 20., 30., 12.]
>>> list_b = [30., 20., 60., 12.]
>>> list_c = [10., 80., 90., 12.]
>>>
>>> [j for i,j in zip(list_a, list_b) if i >= 15]
[20.0, 60.0]
>>>
>>> [j for i,j in zip(list_a, list_c) if i >= 15]
[80.0, 90.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_a = [10., 20., 30., 12.]
list_b = [30., 20., 60., 12.]
list_c = [10., 80., 90., 12.]
drop = [i for i,v in enumerate(list_a) if v <=15]
b = [v for i,v in enumerate(list_b) if not i in drop]
c = [v for i,v in enumerate(list_c) if not i in drop]
```

Comment: This isn't a complete answer. Please add an explanation too, for future reference